Searching for a term for the content of the hadith
We all know the expression "Hadith".
A hadith consists of a chain of transmission and the content: an episode, saying, or similar.
There are many ahadith with different chains but with similar or even identical content.
I am searching for a term to refer to this content related by a group or ahadith.
I thought to use in English: narrative, narration, account, but they are also related to the one who tells it.
Is there a term in Arabic or English that is established in Islamic scolar's or Islamic scientist's literature to denote the (group of) transmitted content?

The content of a hadith is called matn.

متن is the text or the body of each hadith. Muslim mostly assembles several ahadith with more or less the same matn, and adds some notes on variants he heard. How would you say to that group of ahadith?
